# select without from sql (outer apply)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In Sql, you can do something like this below

```
select 1, 2, 3
```

This is the select statement without using 'from'. I just pick up how to use outer apply recently.

Normally you will do outer apply like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM Department D 
OUTER APPLY 
   ( 
   SELECT * FROM Employee E 
   WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID 
   ) A
```

I am wondering if there a way to do this without using the from statement like I mentioned above?

```
For example: 
 Select 1,
        2, 
 OUTER APPLY 
           ( 
              SELECT * FROM Employee E 
             WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID 
           ) E         OUTER APPLY 
   ( 
   SELECT * FROM Employee_Service serv 
   WHERE E.DepartmentID = serv.DepartmentID 
   ) S
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard `outer apply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be close to what you are looking for:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM ( Select 1 AS DepartmentID UNION ALL SELECT 2 ) AS D
 OUTER APPLY 
 ( 
     SELECT * 
     FROM Employee E 
     WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID 
 ) E         
 OUTER APPLY 
 (
     SELECT * 
     FROM Employee_Service serv 
     WHERE E.DepartmentID = serv.DepartmentID 
 ) S
```

or, using [**`VALUES`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM ( VALUES (1), (2) ) AS D(DepartmentID)
 OUTER APPLY 
 ( 
     SELECT * 
     FROM Employee E 
     WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID 
 ) E         
 OUTER APPLY 
 (
     SELECT * 
     FROM Employee_Service serv 
     WHERE E.DepartmentID = serv.DepartmentID 
 ) S
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you want single column with multi row then

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM (Select 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS D(DepartmentID)
OUTER APPLY 
( 
    SELECT * FROM Employee E 
    WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID 
) E         
OUTER APPLY 
( 
    SELECT * FROM Employee_Service serv 
    WHERE E.DepartmentID = serv.DepartmentID 
) S
```

If you want single row with multi columns then

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM (Select 1 DepartmentID,2 DepartmentName,..) AS D
OUTER APPLY 
( 
    SELECT * FROM Employee E 
    WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID 
) E         
OUTER APPLY 
( 
    SELECT * FROM Employee_Service serv 
    WHERE E.DepartmentID = serv.DepartmentID 
) S
```

Comment: Thanks for your help